# Como buscar texto en toda la base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

He visto un post con la funcion buscarcadena aqui en stackoverflow, pero no me funciona, no encuentra cadenas que estoy seguro si están.

La idea es conseguir un texto especifico para poder modificarlo, pero no se en cual de mis mas de 4 mil tablas se encuentra.

uso postgresql

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask] y de paso Checa el [tour], considera editar y agregar un ejemplo, así como tú consulta y demás datos que ayuden a entender tu problema

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta e incluye una descripción más clara de lo que intentas hacer, qué buscas, cómo son tus tablas, cuál es la función que dices que no te funciona, qué error te sale, cuál es la salida esperada y un ejemplo de cómo están definidas tus tablas